# How to display error icon inside input field using Bootstrap and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple form, `Name` and `Email`. I am getting validation error proper but not getting icon inside the input field. I am getting cross icon top right corner.Would you help me out in this?

I am getting output
[image]

I need output like this

[image]

```js
$('#myform').validate({    
    rules: {
        name: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
         email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $( element ).attr("id") + "1";
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');         
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $( element ).attr("id") + "1";
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');         
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.length) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        } 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<form class="form-horizontal" id="myform">
<input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="name" id="name">
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="name1"></span>

<input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="email"><span id="status"></span>
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="email1"></span>

</form>
```

Comment: well simple solution is to set a background icon of error for the input and control its visibility based on the error status

Comment: I don't see any `.form-group` in your HTML, and I'm wondering why you are doing anything like `var id_attr = "#" + $( element ).attr("id") + "1";`. If you wrap the inputs in an `input-group` then you could just select the child with `$(parent).find('.form-control-feedback")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just merge the styling with your CSS and remove the important part. Also a little tweak in your markup.

```js
$('#myform').validate({    
    rules: {
        name: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
         email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $( element ).attr("id") + "1";
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');         
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        var id_attr = "#" + $( element ).attr("id") + "1";
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');         
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.length) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        } 
 });
```

```css
.field-container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.form-control-feedback {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
}
.glyphicon-ok {
  color: #4FAC34;
}
.glyphicon-remove {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<form class="form-horizontal" id="myform">
<div class="field-container">
<input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="name" id="name">
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="name1">x</span>
</div>
<div class="field-container">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="email"><span id="status"></span>
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="email1">x</span>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.aavrug.I check your output I am getting cross sign outside of input field.

Comment: Its working for me now. I tried  position: absolute;top: 10px; right:16px; in class form-control-feedback. working perfectly.I need one help i have to change the color of cross sign.If details are right than color green  or red.can you help me in this also?

Comment: That should be done with JS or If you are adding any type of class on successfully validated input then you can play with that class using CSS.

Comment: Can you help me with any link? so that I can  refer it.

Comment: Added CSS you can see the changes in snippet.

Comment: Mr.aavrug, It's changing the text color. I need to change the color of sign

Comment: But the js adding a tick sign if it's validate true. Do you want that tick sign in green and cross sign in red? Btw added CSS for signs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131211/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-aavrug).

Comment: Thanks for helping me Mr.aavrug.Just need one more information like incase in future if I want to change the tick sign and cross sign then how can I change it?

Comment: Can we use font awesome icon?

Comment: Yes you can use anything that you want.

Comment: Thanks for help Mr.aavrug

Answer (score 0):

Use input-groups to link an icon to an inputfield, then just hide the span by default and show it in your validation function.

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-times"></i></span>
    </div>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/084w9en1/1/

Comment: Sorry Mr.Shadowfox. still same issue.

Comment: Thanks for again reply Mr.Shadowfox. I have that code which you added right now.I have to set according to above image in question.

Answer (score 0):

Use cross icon of bootstrap

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="name" id="name">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove cross" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-group{
    position:relative;
 }

 span.glyphicon-remove.cross{
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;// put the proper position of that cross from top
    right: 0;// put the proper position of that cross from right
 }
```

Comment: Sorry Taniya, Still I am getting icon top right corner.

Comment: because your form is taking the full width of your page. put your form within <div class="container"><div class="col-md-6"></div></div>

Comment: Same issue I am getting. Can you make JSfiddle for me? So that I can easily understand